# How to set WYSIWYG editor width within wp_editor() function?

Tags: wp-editor, wysiwyg

This is my current code:

```
$initial_data = $this->options['my_plugin_editor'];
$settings = array(
    'quicktags' => array('buttons' => 'em,strong,link',),
    'quicktags' => true,
    'tinymce' => true,
    'textarea_rows' => 20,
);
$id = 'my_plugin_editor_options[my_plugin_editor]';
wp_editor($initial_data,$id,$settings);
```

The problem is I am unable to set the width of the editor. I can set the height `'textarea_rows' => 20`, but I am not aware of a way how to set the width(cols).

If I am using a standard textarea without an editor, this is working well `cols="120"`

How to set cols in wp_editor function?

Answer (score 13):

There are two parameters that you can use to change the size of the text editor generated with `wp_editor()`, here there are:

```
$settings = array(
    'editor_height' => 425, // In pixels, takes precedence and has no default value
    'textarea_rows' => 20,  // Has no visible effect if editor_height is set, default is 20
);
```

- If `editor_height` is provided, its raw value will be used
- Otherwise `textarea_rows` (or it's default value of 20) will be used to calculate the matching height in pixels

#### Good to know:

Here are a few examples of the result of the conversion from `textarea_rows` to pixels (this is done on the client side):

- 0 to 3 => 100
- 4 => 113
- 5 => 133
- 10 => 230
- 15 => 328
- **20 => 425**
- ...

Comment: I thing that the question was about width not height.

Answer (score 4):

```
$settings = array(
    'tinymce' => array(
        'width' => 200
    )
);
```

Gives you a tinymce that is 200px wide. Found it here: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration

When I tried it the background color of my tinymce changed. So maybe you have to tweak that.

Comment: It has worked like a charm, thanks

Answer (score 2):

OK, here's what I just did that works well:

```
echo "<div style='width:75%;'>";
wp_editor( $content, 'myid', $settings );
echo "</div>";
```

Comment: While I suppose this works, I suggest adding the parameter instead, as outlined in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you even can set the cols"number" in the array.

But one way to achieve what you want, would be by adding a class to your wp_editor.

```
 $settings = array(
'quicktags' => array('buttons' => 'em,strong,link',),
'quicktags' => true,
'tinymce' => true,
'textarea_rows' => 20,
 'classes' => 'yourclass',
 );
```

or when you're calling the wp_editor:

```
 <?php wp_editor( $content, $editor_id, $settings = array('editor_class'=>'yourclass') ); ?>
```

Then just set width in css:

```
 .yourclass {
   width: 400px !important; //add !important if your style is being overriden 
 }
```