# How to display shorter version of wp_editor?

Tags: visual-editor

You can use `wp_editor` to display the wordpress rich editor. How can I display the shorter version (Please see the screenshot, I need that) of `wp_editor`?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You will want to pass some parameters into your `$settings` array for `wp_editor()` that only tells it to display the quicktags for `strong`,`em`,`ul`,`ol`, and `link` per your screenshot.

I didn't have time to test it, but this code should give you want you want:

```
$settings = array(
   // Any previous settings you are currently using     
   'quicktags' => array( 'buttons' => 'strong,em,ul,ol,link' ),
);

wp_editor( '', 'my-short-editor', $settings );
```

You can replace `'my-short-editor'` with anything but keep in mind this will be the `id` attribute for the resulting editor when rendered.

Answer (score 2):

this is following code for your editor shorter version.

```
 $settings = array(
 'quicktags' => array('buttons' => 'em,strong,link',),
 'quicktags' => true,
 'tinymce' => true,
'textarea_rows' => 20,
 'classes' => 'yourclass',
);
```

or when you're calling the wp_editor:

```
<?php wp_editor( $content, $editor_id, $settings = array('editor_class'=>'yourclass') ); ?>
```

Then just set width in css:

```
 .yourclass {
   width: 400px !important; //add !important if your style is being overriden 
}
```

hope this will help you. For more [URL 1](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/114311/remove-specific-buttons-from-wp-editor), [URL 2](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/112441/how-to-set-wysiwyg-editor-width-within-wp-editor-function)